# getting same results twice...not showing distinct..distinct in not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Getting same results twice...not showing distinct..distinct in not     working...distinct not working..same database values or homogeneous database values showing ..it has to be unique

```
model

public function get_all_userDocside()  
{  


//data is retrive from this query  


$this->db->LIMIT(6);
 $this->db->order_by('rand()');
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('*');  

        $this->db->from("tbl_doctor");
        $this->db->join("tbl_specialisation", "tbl_specialisation.spec_id = tbl_doctor.spec_id",'left');



        $query = $this->db->get();
        //var_dump($query);die();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
          return $query;
        }
}
```

Comment: Which field in your SQL should be distinct?

Comment: tbl_doctor.district   &  tbl_specialisation.spec_specialise

Comment: $this->db->group_by('tbl_doctor.district');

Comment: exactly! you need to add group_by() since codeigniter won't allow you to mention which field needs to be distinct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter distinct mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130905/codeigniter-distinct-mysql-query)